# Uvicorn, NGINX, Django

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, uvicorn

Использую для деплоя `Django` проекта `nginx` и `gunicorn`

Решил попробовать `uvicorn`

Запустить то получается, только вот связать `uvicorn` и `nginx` никак.

Конфиг `nginx`

```
...

http {
    ...

    upstream uvicorn {
        server unix:/home/dhvcc/PycharmProjects/dwapper/dwapper.sock;
    }
}
```

Конфиг проекта

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    return 301 https://0.0.0.0:80$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/dwapper.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/dwapper.key;
    # DJANGO
    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off; log_not_found off;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/dhvcc/PycharmProjects/dwapper/staticfiles/;
    }
    # UVICORN
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://uvicorn;
    }
}
```

При попытке зайти на сайт в лог получаю

```
*205 connect() to unix:/home/dhvcc/PycharmProjects/dwapper/dwapper.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://unix:/home/dhvcc/PycharmProjects/dwapper/dwapper.sock:/", host: "localhost"
```

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что `uvicorn` не запущен. Запускаю я так (--uds явно указывает на тот сокет)

```
/home/dhvcc/PycharmProjects/dwapper/venv/bin/uvicorn  --workers 3 --uds unix:/home/dhvcc/PycharmProjects/dwapper/dwapper.sock dwapper.asgi:application
```

Только запуск почему-то просиходит на `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

`dwapper.sock` - файл, сгенерированный ещё во время работы с `gunicorn`

Вот старый конфиг сервиса, под которым работал `gunicorn`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=dhvcc
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/dhvcc/PycharmProjects/dwapper
ExecStart=/home/dhvcc/PycharmProjects/dwapper/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/dhvcc/PycharmProjects/dwapper.sock dwapper.wsgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: может права на сокет ... а вариант с TCP чем плох?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov user root имеет права. Да и гуникорн ведь работает спокойно и локально и в проде

Comment: вариант направить nginx на `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov сервер должен быть доступен сети и необходима возможность доступа по https. Даже при запуске на 127 NGINX не может подключиться, как если бы сервер не был запущен. Может, нужно как-то сгенерировать новый сокет файл?

Comment: `Только запуск почему-то просиходит на http://127.0.0.1:8000`. это uvicorn так? Если туда напрямую `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000` запутить, он работает? тогда делаем `proxy_pass` туда же.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112405/discussion-between-dhvcc-and-sergei-kirjanov).

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, этот вариант сработал, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположительно `uvicorn` поднялся на `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

Это можно проверить: `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000`.
Даже если возвращается код `301`, это уже значит, что сервер отвечает.

Тогда `proxy_pass` у `nginx` можно направить напрямую туда же.

unix-сокеты использоваться не будут, и заметной выгоды от них вероятно не было бы.